# A consequence of the invariance of domain by Brouwer

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, algebraic-topology

**Theorem (of the invariance of domain).** If $U$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuous and injective application, then $f(U)$ is open.

**Consequence**. If $U$ is a non empty open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then an application $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^m$ continuous and injective cannot exists if $m<n$. In particular, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$ iff $m=n$.

*Proof*.  By absurd, let $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^m$ continuous and injective and take the immersion $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $\varphi(\mathbf{x})=(\mathbf{x},0,...,0)$. Clearly, $\varphi$ is continuous and injective. Let's define $g=\varphi \circ f$. So, $g$ is continuous and injective. The previous theorem gives us that $g(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. But this is not possible because $\forall \mathbf{y}\in g(U)$, $\forall V$ open neighbourhood of $\mathbf{y}$ in $g(U)$, we have that $V\cap (\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \varphi(\mathbb{R}^m))\ne \emptyset$.

It's all clear but I can't understand why the last intersection is non empty, can you help me?

Comment: Draw a picture. Seriously. Ask yourself why the line is not open in $\Bbb R^2$, why **no** subsets of the line are open in $\Bbb R^2$. Ask why no subsets of the plane can be open in $\Bbb R^3$, etc.

Comment: Oh, I got it now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u = (u_1, ..., u_n) \in U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \implies f(u) = ((fu)_1,..., (fu)_m) \in f(U) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m \implies g(u) = ((fu)_1,..., (fu)_m,0,...,0) \in g(U) \in \mathbb{R}^n$

now let $y \in g(U)$, and consider any open ball $B(y, r)$: the point

$y' = (y_1,...,y_m, \frac{r}{2}, 0, ..., 0) \in B(y, r)$

yet $y' \notin g(U)$, so $B(y, r) \nsubseteq g(U)$, hence $g(U)$ is not open